# How to propagate default arguments between functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has [default arguments for function and constructor parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments). Now, I have a function

```
fun foo(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42) {}
```

and I want to call it from different places but also retain the possibility to not pass on of the arguments and instead use the default value.

I know, I can declare the default arguments in the calling functions

```
fun foo2(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42) {
    // do stuff
    foo(bar, baz)
}

fun foo3(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42) {
    // do other stuff
    foo(bar, baz)
}
```

but now my default parameter in `foo` is pointless as it's always overwriten and I have duplicated the default arguments in all calling functions. That's not very DRY.

Is there a better way to propagate the default arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having three functions with the same default arguments:

```
fun foo(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42)
fun foo2(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42)
fun foo3(bar: String = "ABC", baz: Int = 42)
```

Create a wrapper class that takes in the arguments, and have the functions without parameters:

```
class Foo(val bar: String = "ABC", val baz: Int = 42) {

  fun foo() { /* ... */ }

  fun foo2() {
    // ...
    foo()
  }

  fun foo3() {
    // ...
    foo()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Answering my own question as encouraged by [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).</sub>

---

What you can do, is declare the parameters in the calling functions as nullable and use `null` as the default argument:

```
fun foo2(bar: String? = null: Int? = null) {
    // do stuff
    foo(bar, baz)
}

fun foo3(bar: String? = null, baz: Int? = null) {
    // do other stuff
    foo(bar, baz)
}
```

Then, use one of the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to use default values, when `null` is provided.

```
fun foo(bar: String? = null, baz: Int? = null) {
    val realBar = bar ?: "ABC"
    val realBaz = baz ?: 42
}
```

If you're dealing with a class instead of a function, you can pull out the property of the constructor and assign the default value there:

```
class Foo(bar: String? = null, baz: Int? = null) {
    val bar = bar ?: "ABC"
    val baz = baz ?: 42
}
```

Alternatively, say if your class is a `data class` and you want to have the properties in the primary constructor, you can declare a factory method to handle the default values:

```
class Foo(val bar: String, baz: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun create(bar: String? = null, baz: Int? = null) = Foo(bar ?: "ABC", baz ?: 42)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple functions taking the same arguments (with the same default values), then that is a code-smell suggesting that those parameters are closely related and should live inside their own class.

```
data class FooArgs( val bar: String = "ABC", val baz: Int = 42 )

fun foo( args: FooArgs = FooArgs() ) { /* ... */}

fun foo2( args: FooArgs = FooArgs() ) {
  ...
  foo(args)
}

fun foo3( args: FooArgs = FooArgs() ) {
  ...
  foo(args)
}
```

If `foo` and/or `foo2`, `foo3` only use their arguments, then further refactoring would move `foo` and `foo2` into the `FooArgs` class, resulting in a similar solution to [the answer by @nhaarman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720751/221955)